# Store the result of a function as a variable

Tags: python, rsa

I'm trying to write an RSA code, but I'm having issues with a simple thing. I want to store the result of a function as a variable, twice in Python. This is my code

```
def random_odd_between(j,k):
    k1 = (k-1)//2
    j1 = j//2
    a1 = int(random()*(k1-j1+1))+j1
    a = 2*a1 +1
    return a

# The list of primes less than 10^6 is given by:
list_of_primes = prime_range(1,10^6)

# Write a function to check if given number is prime:
def check_if_prime(n):
    prime_flag = 1
    for i in list_of_primes:
        checker = n%i
        if checker != 0:
            if (n/i) in ZZ:
                prime_flag = 0
        break
    else:
        prime_flag = 0
        break
    return prime_flag

# Generate random numbers between 6*10^9 and 10^10 until we get a prime.
# Generate two prime numbers between 6*10^9 and 10^10 for p and q
def get_a_prime():
    count = 0
    prime_found = 0
    while prime_found == 0:
        a = random_odd_between(6*10^9,10^10)
        prime_found = check_if_prime(a)
        count = count + 1
# Print a prime you've got:
    print '%i' %a

p = get_a_prime()
q = get_a_prime()
n = p*q

# Let t stand for totient

t = (p-1)*(q-1)
```

I can't get my p and q to be defined however, they keep just giving me an error. I realize I need to do some kind of return, but I can't get the syntax right

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, in your `get_a_prime` method you are not returning anything. You probably want to return something so that it gets stored in p and q.

Comment: As is, one or more `break` statements above are not nested correctly.

Comment: What is ZZ in your code?

Comment: By simply pasting your code in PyCharm, the error is highlighted automatically, and the issue you have becomes much easier to solve. I highly suggest you get either PyCharm (free for non-commercial academic etc) or some [other IDE](http://sopython.com/wiki/Python_IDEs).

Answer (score 4):

just replace `print '%i' %a` with `return a`

Comment: Error in lines 50-50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/sage/sage-6.10/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 947, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "", line 5, in get_a_prime
  File "", line 4, in random_odd_between
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
73

Comment: Line 50 is prime_found = 0

Comment: @CoriVanderWerf This does indeed solve the problem in your question. The error you mention is a different issue you ll have to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had errors in both your `check_if_prime` and `get_a_prime` functions.  In the former, `ZZ` is not defined and the first `break` should be indented one more level and the last one is redundant.  Better yet, just return True or False when needed.

In the second function, you need to return the value that is prime rather than just print it.

```
def check_if_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True  # 2 is a prime.
    if n % 2 == 0 or n <= 1:
        return False  # Anything less than or equal to one is not prime.

    for divisor in xrange(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2):  # 3, 5, 7, ..., int(SQRT(n)) + 1
        if not n % divisor:  
            return False  # NOT divisible by the divisor.

    return True  # Must be prime.

def get_a_prime():
    prime_found = False
    while not prime_found:
        a = random_odd_between(6 * 10 ^ 9, 10 ^ 10)
        prime_found = check_if_prime(a)
    return a
```

**Testing**

```
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101]

# Ensure all primes above are prime per our function.
>>> all(check_if_prime(n) for n in primes)
True

# Ensure all numbers in range 0-101 that is not identified as a prime is not a prime.
>>> any(check_if_prime(n) for n in xrange(102) if n not in primes)
False
```

Comment: Which version of Python and what was the error?  This is for Python 2.7.  For Python 3, change `xrange` to `range`.

Comment: Oops.  Something missed my final edit.  Please see slight revision above.